# increasing the size of root partition and reducing the size of home

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to take 20G from my `/home` and put it in my `/`. I logged into live installation drive and launched `gparted`.

The partitions look like this:

[image]

`sda4` is root, `sda5` is boot and `sda6` my home partition.

If I click on `sda6` and resize it from left to right I will get a warning that `moving partition might cause your operating system to fail to boot` and after that partitions look like this:
[image]

Now there is `sda5`(my boot partition) in the way and the only way is to move it to the right of my unallocated space like this:

[image]

Now I can merge unallocated space with root:

[image]

**If I click apply will l`gparted` be able to generate new `fstab` or do I have to do it manually?**

Comment: gparted won't update fstab, but it is not necessary. But you will need to re-install grub, because you moved the starting point of `/boot`.

Comment: Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614728/increasing-the-size-of-root-partition-and-reducing-the-size-of-home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fstab` won't need updating if UUIDs of your partitions dodn't change. But it is worth checking.

But you'll need to re-install grub.

Comment: so I should re-install grub after gparted finishes or do I need to boot into live usb and fix that after reboot?

Comment: You fix it from LiveUSB. But you'll need to mount your `/boot` and chroot there.